# How to use each(..) function in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, underscore.js

```
_.each(key_val, function(e){
            if($.inArray(e[0], names) == -1){
                var node = {};
                node.name = e[0];
                if(e[1]) {
                    node.value = e[1];
                    node.symbolSize = e[1] * nodeProp;
                }
                optionNodes.push(node);
                names.push(e[0]);
            }
        });
```

Above code from used angular.js I have to incorporate in angular typescript.
here is "key_val" is array

Comment: Can you elaborate what actually you want to do. Little more description would be helpful to understand.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: `map` is better than each or forEach function

Comment: need more details, it will be useful to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what your function is doing, you can create an array of object with name & value keys like this -

```
let key_val = [{name: 'c', value: 'xyz'}, {name: 'd', value: ''}];
```

Assuming you also have an array of names like -

```
let names = ['a', 'b'];
```

To iterate over each object in key_val array, you can use map like this -

```
key_val.map(item => {
  if(names.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {  //checking if item.name is present in names array or not
    var node = {};
    node.name = item.name;
    if(item.value) {
       node.value = item.name;
       node.symbolSize = item.name * nodeProp;
    }
    optionNodes.push(node);
    names.push(item.name);
  }
});
```